# Is there any system that can authenticate my device to open only select apps on it?

Tags: authentication, device-locking

I am looking to have an authentication system with which I can link a device to an employee, and then put in place certain privileges so that the employee is only able to open select apps on only that device.

These select, in-house apps can only run on these authenticated devices, not on any outside devices, and the apps can be diverse, like PHP based websites, email services, or other mobile apps.

Comment: You just described "Mobile Device Management" - there are several different products that deliver this.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for mobile apps, full PCs (Windows/Mac/Linux), or something else? There are lots of systems to do device management / software restrictions, but they are not generally cross-platform so it matters what platform you're using. Also, be advised that a skilled person with unrestricted physical access to the device can usually bypass such restrictions, if they put the effort into it.

Comment: not entirely sure what you are asking. Maybe related to this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155752/restrict-a-specific-app-to-run-only-on-mdm-provisioned-devices

Answer (score 1):

Answer depends on the service you may refer.

For example if it's a web services (php as you've indicated), an authentication mechanism with authorization limits user rights. You may control the user based on the privilege assigned to the user profile.

For Apps installed on a device you may deploy password protection for applications where the user will be asked for authentication when accessing app. There are several similar apps available in market. following are some examples:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/password-protection/9nblggh1p2gx

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/applocker-lock-your-apps/9wzdncrd23mg